# I'm migrating a J2EE app from JBoss to Websphere

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, websphere, message-driven-bean

I'm migrating a J2EE app from JBoss to Websphere.  It was written about 15 years ago by folks who are no longer with our company.  It's written using EJB 2.0 technology (moving it to 3.0 isn't currently on the radar).  I'm currently struggling with configuring a ActivationSpec to allow my Message Based Bean talk with the JMS queue being used for interal routing.

I believe the error I'm getting is basically telling me that the JNDI lookup to retrieve the authorizationAlias is failing (but I could be mistaken).

Here's what I get in the log file:

```
[5/15/17 13:35:03:279 CDT] 0000004f AbstractEJBRu I   CNTR0180I: The <bean name> message-driven bean in the <module name> module of the <app name> application is bound to the asHostRequest activation specification.
[5/15/17 13:35:03:310 CDT] 0000004f ActivationSpe E   J2CA0155W: The lookup of the AuthenticationAlias asHostRequest, assigned to the ActivationSpec asHostRequest (com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jmsra.impl.JmsJcaActivationSpecImpl) by application <app name>#<module name>#<bean name> has failed.
[5/15/17 13:35:03:310 CDT] 0000004f ActivationSpe W   J2CA0149W: The contents of the AuthenticationAlias assigned to the ActivationSpec asHostRequest (com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jmsra.impl.JmsJcaActivationSpecImpl) used by MDB <app name>#<module name>#<bean name> are invalid. The UserName and/or the Password were either null or blank. The AuthenticationAlias was: asHostRequest, its UserName was: null, and its Password was: null
[5/15/17 13:35:03:357 CDT] 0000004f SibMessage    I   [:] CWSIV0777I: A connection to messaging engine SBYRDLPTW10Node03.server1-<bus name> for destination HostResponse on bus <bus name> has been successfully created.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you did create an Activation specification in WebSphere and an Authentication Alias in WebSphere, correct?